# Pagination is not consistent/working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-pagination, jquery-ui-plugins

I have 8000 rows of data in JSON format available in the client-side, after making an Ajax call to the database in JavaScript, that I need to populate into HTML tables for display.

I am trying to run the code below but I face the following problems:
since I have large data, when I query on a web interface, several Ajax calls are made to pull data  from a database and displays the same on the HTML page.

I am facing the following problems:

1. I see pagination only when the result is very large
2. When pagination appears, all data is loaded on the page at first, not the 10 or 25 per page and so my jQuery script becomes unresponsive. But after I toggle the paging size filter-10,25,50,or 100, the right number of results appear.

The code I am trying is below.

HTML:

```
    <table id="tableprint" class="data-grid" size="50">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Profession</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
success: function(data) {
   $('#tableprint').dataTable({
      "aaData": jsonArrayOfjsonObjects.json, //this is a json with 8000 table rows of data
      "aoColumnsDef": [{
         "mData": "name"
      }, {
         "mData": "age"
      }, {
         "mData": "profession"
      }, {
         "mData": "address"
      }, {
         "mData": "comments",
         "defaultContent": "Empty"
      }, ],
      "bDestroy": true
   }).fnDestroy();

   $('#tableprint').dataTable({
      "bDestroy": true
   }).fnDestroy();
}
```

FYI, I am destroying the datatable instance as I got the "cannot reinstantiate DataTable" error and this was the recommended solution for this.

```
   $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'sendData',
        data : { //Send form data to the Servlet
            sid : sid,
            mpid : mpid
        },
        success : function(data) {
            $('#tableprint').dataTable({
               "aaData" : data.ActionsArr,
               "bPaginate":"true",
               "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
               // etc..
        }
```

The above Ajax Post, is called everytime the user clicks on the submit button on the form with a different `sid` and `mpid` values.

Included JS files:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Without access to the table (perhaps a jsFiddle unless your data is confidential) it'd be difficult to tell. I'd prefer not to reinitialize the table but rather to create it once and then clear it and populate it again as per http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5158/how-do-i-reload-datatables-with-new-json-data.

Will you be reloading the data from the server?

Comment: In your code you're destroying the table you've just created, doesn't make much sense. You mention that you use multiple Ajax calls, are you calling your function when **all** Ajax calls are successful? Show your code for that if possible. Also what DataTables version are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question with the ajax call code in the end of the question details

Comment: You say: *when I query on a web interface, several Ajax calls are made to pull data from a database*. There is only one ajax call, how do you make multiple calls to `sendData`? That may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Everytime I sumbit  an html form in the jsp page, The ajax call is issued to bring back data from the database. It's actually one call for each time

Answer (score -1):

Add the following:

```
 "paging": true,
 "pageLength": 25, //or whatever you want the page length to be
```

after this line:

```
"aaData" : jsonArrayOfjsonObjects.json,
```